# SSIS passing source data as parameter to another source data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've already data in my SQLServer database extracted from Sybase. I need to continue extracting information from Sybase considering the data stored in SQLServer. Basically is a condition `where not in` from a diffrent database.

[image]

Comment: You need to get get all the data from A (SQL Server) where the ID doesn't exist in B (Sybase)? How much data are you dealing with? Is it a simple match (id = id) or do you need to do something complex like date boundaries?

Comment: Without more detail my thought as to what you're going to need is a look-up.

Comment: billinkc, you're rigth. the match is basically id = id. The A (SQL Server) has historical information and I want to add just the new data. I do not know how much data is due to I'm doing an example previous to get full information but I think is about 100K records (5K monthly)

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are getting new data based on id=id, you can do lookup operation where you can cache all ids(assuming this is primary key of source data) imported already in SQL Server and do lookup.
2) Otherwise, if you are importing based on some timestamp column, you can store the maximum imported date of data which was imported in last cycle in some table and you can use that to where clause of source query dynamically to identify new rows.

Comment: This case is the number 1. But I would like to prevent to select all id's from my source and then to do a lookup. But I coudn't find any other solution until now.